# How to get each sub categories from a parent category through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to list subcategories when i select the parent category through JQuery. 
Here i'm getting only last item of subcategory when i click  the parent category.

How to get all items belongs to that parent?

```js
function update_subscategories_div(parent_id) { 
   var result={},objectlength
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/get_subscategories/"+parent_id+".json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"parent_id" : parent_id},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      result = JSON.parse(data)
      objectlength =result.length
      for(var i=0; i<objectlength; i++)
      {
        var name = jQuery("#categoriesDiv").html(result[i].name);
      }
      console.log(name);
      console.log(objectlength);
    }
  });
}
```

Table 
[image: Table]

Comment: Using this var name = jQuery("#categoriesDiv").html(result[i].name); it will replace your code every time while your for loop is running. First you have to store these values in array whose coming from for loop. Then print this array according to your requirement.

Comment: @  Deepak saini can you just edit the code , i don't have much knowledge in array looping

Comment: Do you need this in dropdown option?

Comment: yes i need the result  in dropdown option, not in same dropdown ,in other

Comment: Did you checked my answer?

Comment: getting the output, but in the subcategories in select option is not clearing , when i select the second parent element. it contains first and second subcategories item and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90388/discussion-between-deepak-saini-and-sreena).

Comment: in success fucntion add this jQuery("#selectprarentId").find('option').remove(); before the for loop start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery("#categoriesDiv").html(result[i].name);
```

Replace this with below one.

```
jQuery("#categoriesDiv").append('<option>'+result[i].name+'</option>');
```

I think **categoriesDiv** this id should be of select box.
ex:

```
<select id="categoriesDiv">
    </select>
```

And add this before for loop In success function **jQuery("#selectprarentId").find('option').remove();**

then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a global array and add every subcategory to that array in a for loop and return that at the end.

```
    var subcat = [];//Array of subcategories
    for (var i = 0; i < objectlength; i++) {
        subcat.push(result[i].name);

}
```

Similarly now you can loop on subcat array as above.

Comment: can you please share the code for looping through array.

Comment: @sreena check my answer i have updated that for array populating.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
 for(var i=0; i<objectlength; i++)
 {
      var name = jQuery("#categoriesDiv").html(result[i].name);
 }
```

You're redefining the value for `name` in each iteration. That is why you get the last value in your subcategories.

Change your code to look like

```
var name = "";
var categoriesDiv = jQuery("#categoriesDiv");
for(var i=0; i<objectlength; i++){
    var currentText = categoriesDiv .html();
    var newText = currentText+' '+ result[i].name;
    categoriesDiv .html(newText );
    name += ' ' + result[i].name; // this may not be necessary
}
console.log(categoryArray);
console.log(objectlength);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function update_subscategories_div(parent_id) { 
   var result={},objectlength;
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/get_subscategories/"+parent_id+".json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"parent_id" : parent_id},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
     jQuery("#categoriesDiv").find('option').remove();
      result = JSON.parse(data);
      objectlength =result.length;
      for(var i=0; i<objectlength; i++)
      {
        jQuery("#categoriesDiv").append('<option>'+result[i].name+'</option>');
      }
      console.log(name);
      console.log(objectlength);
    }
  });
}
```